# Accessing right image resource on different devices at run time

Tags: android

I have to change the background image of the android application at the run time.I understood from blogs and google search that i cant modify the asset or res/drawable folders at the tun time to store images.

So I am storing images in internal storage at run time to display as background image in the android application.But how can I access the right image resource on different devices programatically similar to res\drawable\hdpi, res\drawable\mdpi etc resolution folders.

```
public String saveImageToInternalSorage(Context context, Resources resources)
{

    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
    // path to /data/data/[app name]/app_imageDir
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Create imageDir
    File mypath;
    Bitmap bitmapImage;
    if (isLandscape()) {
        mypath = new File(directory, "bg_repository_menu_landscape.jpg");
        bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.bg_repository_menu_landscape);
    }
    else {
        mypath = new File(directory, "bg_repository_menu_portrait.jpg");
        bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.bg_repository_menu_portrait);
    }

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {

        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}


public Drawable loadImageFromInternalStorage(String path, Resources resources)
{
    //DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    //int densityDpi = (int) (metrics.density * 160f);
    File file;
    try {
        if (isLandscape()) {
            file = new File(path, "bg_repository_menu_landscape.jpg");
        }
        else {
            file = new File(path, "bg_repository_menu_portrait.jpg");
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file));

        // bitmap.setDensity(densityDpi);

        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap);
        return drawable;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: usually, the device itself decides which one to pick. So if You refer to the drawables folder, it will take the right picture from the right folder. The only thing You have to do is, to set the same filename in every folder.

Comment: Thanks for the info.I have to store the images in internal storage at the run time and access it at the run time.

Comment: So what is the question then? It seems like you have a plan; store them somewhere in runtime (persist the location) and then use them in runtime. seems like you don't need any help.

Comment: If i am storing the images in some folder in the internal storage, how the application will pick the right resolution image ?

Comment: what is the way you using to store the images ?

Comment: Edited the question description with code snippets to store the images and load the images

Answer (score 1):

You can access the DPI of the device using:

```
int getDeviceDpi() {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return densityDpi = (int)(metrics.density * 160f);
}
```

Then take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to decide if it's hdpi, ldpi, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
                // show image for landscape
                Log.d(TAG, "LANDSCAPE");
            }
            else {
                // show image for potrait
                Log.d(TAG, "PORTRAIT");
            }
```